# What does the note from chapter 14 say?

Tags: japanese-language, school-ningyo

Here's the note from the last chapter:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Utter this incantation!
>   If you don't, you won't be able to see mermaids.
>
> ↓
>
> Mermaid, mermaid
>   I beg of you
>   Make my love come true
>   For me, [do something with] blood and flesh
>
> (end of incantation)

(I know nothing about this manga. The last line of the incantation has an implied verb; one would need context in order to determine what verb should go there.)

Comment: Oh, so it's the usual spell, man that just indicates that it'll go on forever! I seriously thought the slit mouth woman (ironic because that's another popular Japanese Urban Legend) had written down her new founding about the mermaids since she found out that they become aggressive and attack out of jealousy when a GiRl whose love is actually requinted chants the incantation. Instead the notebook will be passed on forever! (×__× ; )

Comment: @Imōto if this answer has helped you, please accept it by pressing the checkmark button.